# MAX LOCS PER TRANSCATION in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am getting error in postgres "MAX_LOCS_PER_TRANSCATION".

Can anybody please suggestion the solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the database above ran out of locks was that a few sessions were holding up to 1800 locks, most of them RowExclusiveLock. Given that a lock in Postgres is usually a lock on an object (like a table or part of a table) and not on a row, holding 1800 locks in one transaction is somewhat unusual.

so you need to increase it's value
you can refer below links :
http://www.databasesoup.com/2012/06/postgresqlconf-maxlockspertransaction.html